# Merge objects in an array based on other values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, merge

I'm trying to merge a set of strings in an array based on a series of matching properties and remove the items that were duplicates.

My current array:

```
{id: "12", value: "Option 1"},
{id: "55", value: "Option A"},
{id: "55", value: "Option B"},
{id: "55", value: "Option C"},
{id: "55", value: "Option D"},
{id: "106", value: "Option 1"}
```

I want to merge all items with the id of '55' so my array will look like this:

```
{id: "12", value: "Option 1"},
{id: "55", value: "Option A, Option B, Option C, Option D"},
{id: "106", value: "Option}
```

I can only manage to merge the first 2 items using a for loop and checking the -1 sibling and can't work out to do this without serious bloat to my code.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your for loop code.

Comment: I was using almost exactly what Usman Rana posted (nested for loop) but I forgot the condition i != j and was getting irregularities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an object as a lookup table while storing the results in an array in parallel:

```
const lookup = {}, result = [];

for( const {id, value} of input ){
  if(lookup[id]){
     lookup[id].value += "," + value;
  }else{
     result.push( lookup[id] = {id, value} );
  }
}
```

This is quite new javascript, but it [works](https://tio.run/##fVBLDoIwEN33FJOuICIRE1xIWPjZewDigkjRasM0lLIhPTsWSgKJhu467zPvzTtvc/WouWy2FRas7x9YqQZ4JXUDKWSk48URaLSnAbS50Mx@brLhWEFETTDBcfwLn9bh8zp8WYevMxztDn@zkXtCiGsjED9a2jqdCaBmSoux20AosfbAsazd5GMAy@kEfkcAeOk5i4wX93Fi3zwJRxFsUqABhY3zSCzLMKHYRHdrQ6nVy1toh1CLvf4oI8YlR8FCgU/Paf2k778) on modern engines ;)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late may be. But you can try this with `for/while` loop. It's a very basic approach. And if time complexity is not a concern. Otherwise Jons w's answer is good.

```js
var x = [{id: "12", value: "Option 1"},
{id: "55", value: "Option A"},
{id: "55", value: "Option B"},
{id: "55", value: "Option C"},
{id: "55", value: "Option D"},
{id: "12", value: "Option D"},
{id: "53", value: "Option D"},
{id: "106", value: "Option 1"}];

for(var j =0; j<x.length;j++){
for(var i =0; i<x.length;i++){
  if(x[j].id == x[i].id && i !=j){
     x[j].value = x[j].value + "," +x[i].value;
     x.splice(i, 1);
     }
  }
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Thanks Usman, I was trying a for loop with nested in a for loop but forgot about the i != j and was getting problems. I accepted the top answer as it's  quite a small snippet of code but this is what I would have gone for originally.

Comment: linting, linting, linting... And you need to decrement i after splicing... But still: thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce`.

```js
const data = [{id: "12", value: "Option 1"},{id: "55", value: "Option A"},{id: "55", value: "Option B"},{id: "55", value: "Option C"},{id: "55", value: "Option D"},{id: "106", value: "Option 1"}];

var result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
  return r[o.id] = r[o.id] ? (r[o.id].value += ", " + o.value, r[o.id]) : o, r;
},{})

var output = Object.values(result);
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```